# Parsing HTML with PHP DOMXpath

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, domxpath

I want to retrieve event links and text from an external website using PHP and DOMXpath. The structure of the external website html is below;

```
<!-- first -->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 me recording-item">
    <div class="recording-item-inner">
        <a class="col-sm-12 recording-name" href="/recordings/191">
        <div class="info">
            <b>Daily Event</b><br>
            <small>29 Jun 2020</small>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- second -->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 me recording-item">
    <div class="recording-item-inner">
        <a class="col-sm-12 recording-name" href="/recordings/190">
        <div class="info">
            <b>Daily Event B</b><br>
            <small>26 Jun 2020</small>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- third -->
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-3 me recording-item">
    <div class="recording-item-inner">
        <a class="col-sm-12 recording-name" href="/recordings/189">
        <div class="info">
            <b>Daily Event C</b><br>
            <small>22 Jun 2020</small>
        </div></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the latest 5 event names, dates and links. Currently I can get the latest (single) event using the code below.

```
<?php
function getEvents()
{

    $page = file_get_contents('https://example.com/events');
    $rootUrl = 'https://example.com';

    @$doc = new DOMDocument();
    @$doc->loadHTML($page);

    $xpath = new DomXPath($doc);

    $nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='recording-item']");
    $node = $nodeList->item(0);

    $href = $xpath->evaluate("string(//div[@class='recording-item-inner']/a/@href)");
    $eventUrl = $rootUrl . $href;

    return $eventUrl;

}
?>
```

How can I amend this code so that it retrieves the 5 most recent event details and to print out a simple list of items;

```
<ul>
  <li>Event 1 - [name], [date], [href]</li>
  <li>Event 2 - [name], [date], [href]</li>
  <li>Event 3 - [name], [date], [href]</li>
  <li>Event 4 - [name], [date], [href]</li>
  <li>Event 5 - [name], [date], [href]</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are the event dates always in reverse chronological order or do the events appear randomly in the html?

Comment: @JackFleeting so far they all appear to be in reverse chronological order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done, but because of the limited xpath support, it's not the most elegant solution.

Starting from `$nodeList`; given that your sample xml has only 3 events, this code will output the required information about the first two. Obviously, you can modify it for your actual code:

```
$nodeList = $xpath->query('//div[./div[@class="recording-item-inner"]]//div[@class="info"]');
$i = 1;
echo htmlspecialchars("<ul>", ENT_QUOTES);
echo "<br>";
foreach($nodeList as $result) { 
   if ($i++ > 2) break;
   echo htmlspecialchars("<li>", ENT_QUOTES);
   echo "Event 1 - " . $result->childNodes[1]->textContent . ",   ";
   echo $result->childNodes[4]->textContent . ",   ";
   echo $result->parentNode->getAttribute('href');
   echo htmlspecialchars("</li>", ENT_QUOTES);   
   echo "<br>";
   }
echo htmlspecialchars("</ul>", ENT_QUOTES);
```

Output:

```
<ul>
<li>Event 1 - Daily Event, 29 Jun 2020, /recordings/191</li>
<li>Event 1 - Daily Event B, 26 Jun 2020, /recordings/190</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's working on my localhost environment (XAMPP), however whenever I copy and paste the exact same code to my live environment the date `$result->childNodes[4]->textContent` doesn't display. Here's a var_dump($result) on my localhost https://pastebin.com/2gLU7HHt and here's a dump of my live https://pastebin.com/S8CJtncJ - I can't see any difference apart from the spacing between `textContent` - would this make a difference?

Comment: @jonboy -Yes, definitely the spacing; that's why it took me a while to figure it out. Logically it should be the first and second `childNodes`. It may (or may not) be solved by using `trim()` somewhere in there, but I didn't try it.

Comment: Why would the spacing be different even though the code is the exact same?!

Comment: @jonboy No idea; it must be something about how the newline characters are being interpreted. Obviously, it's very frustrating because it shouldn't happen. FWIW, I tried it other xml parser (in a non PHP environment) - some used the equivalent `childNodes` 1 and 3; others required that `<br>` be replaced with `</br>`, etc.